# Add view under text view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, textview, autolayout

I have a fullsceen textView including much strings, so height of this view automatically changes. Its works nice, but i need to create some newView under this textView.

If I just make constraints like bottom of screen = bottom of newView, top of newView = bottom of textView, so newView will overlap textView.

Comment: you said i have full screen textview , what is constraints of it? , you have two options either fix height of textview or bottom constraint with view .

Answer (score 0):

try add height constraints to your textView with priority is 750.
Now you can build your app and run it again!
Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

Just add your text view to the new view. 
Here you are adding view with same size of textview. So it will over lapping. But if you add your text view subview of view so your main view will go back and text view will come front.

Comment: Can you post screenshot of your simulator.?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your views are trying to fulfil their constraints on fixed screen size.

If you want to keep it on one page (no scrolling) you can either add height constraints to your text view such that its height won't go over certain value or set the bottom view's constraint priority higher so that even when the textview expand it won't overrule bottom view's constraint.

Otherwise you might want to add ScrollView underneath your views. This way when your textview expands the bottom view will get pushed to the bottom outside the screen and you can scroll down the page